# What is a good jquery plugin to do general text processing like highlighting words and stuff like that?

Tags: jquery, string, text, highlighting

I'm not really too familiar with jquery plugins. I don't even know what I would search for, or which plugin has good activity. Jquery might even have the code built inside and I am just not aware.

Basically what I'd like is a plugin to do some "behind the scenes" text processing - not a WYSIWYG. Things like this:

1. Highlight words given some html or a text fragment. Basically it would let me put 'span' tags and let me wrap those words with a provided css class.
2. Look for a word inside of a given html text, and have it give me a snippet of text where I get X characters before the word and X characters after the word with "..." on either side.
3. A way to simply say, "Get rid of all the 'image' tags" in this text block (these are not html - just text).

Is there anything like this that is widely used, robust, etc? I'd rather not have to code this stuff from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

so for your searching, jquery's really not built for the whole string manipulation thing, so i generally drop into regular old javascript and do something like this:

```
var search = 'some'
var matchIdx = $('body').text().search(search);
var charBefore = 5;
var charAfter = 6;
var startingIdx = matchIdx - charBefore;
var endingIdx = matchIdx + search.length + charAfter;

console.log($('body').text())
console.log(matchIdx);
console.log($('body').text().substring(startingIdx,endingIdx));
```

see it working in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KdG2H/)

Answer (score 0):

Codemirror http://codemirror.net/ is nice one.
I'm using it for my projects.

Comment: That's a very cool plugin. Thanks for telling me about it. I actually mean text-processing behind the scenes though - not a gui one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Highlight plugin: http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Comment: Well, that solves one problem ;) Thanks! What about excerpts? Basically what I should have stated was a library similar to Rails' TextHelper. I don't use rails, but basically something like that would be great. The ability to do excerpts though is most important. I could code it, but if someone else has and has made it very robust, then I'd rather use theirs.

Comment: I have not come across anything for what you want. Others have asked but not found a simple solution.